# Unable to install sndfile with pip

Tags: python, c++, jupyter-notebook, data-science-experience

I need to install sndfile. I'm on a Jupyter notebook, Python interpreter on IBM Watson studio.

I already installed the library `libsndfile` with `!conda install -c conda-forge libsndfile`.

When I call `pip install sndfile`, I get as error:

```
...
gcc -pthread -shared -B /home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/compiler_compat -L/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/sndfile._sndfile.o -lsndfile -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/sndfile/_sndfile.abi3.so
/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/compiler_compat/ld: cannot find -lsndfile
...
```

But if I check the folder `/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib` for the library, actually it's there:

```
!ls /home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/libsnd*

/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/libsndfile.a
/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/libsndfile.so
/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/libsndfile.so.1
/home/spark/conda/envs/python3.6/lib/libsndfile.so.1.0.28
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That error message `cannot find -lsndfile` sounds as if the linker is looking for a file named `-lsndfile`, rather than a library `libsndfile.o`. I suspect the command-line options get misinterpreted.